# Using Flickr API to download images -- Python

Tags: python, flickr

I was trying to write a python script to download flickr images based on input keyword. By accessing the [Flickr API](https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi) I got 2 ways to get images:

```
flickr=flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key,api_secret,cache=True)

def flickr_walk(keyward):
    photos = flickr.walk(text=keyward,
                         tag_mode='all',
                         tags=keyward,
                         extras='url_c',
                         per_page=100)

    for photo in photos:
        try:
            url=photo.get('url_c')
            print(url)

        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to download image')
```

Alternatively,

```
def flickr_search(keyward):
    obj = flickr.photos.search(text=keyward,
                               tags=keyward,
                               extras='url_c',
                               per_page=5)

    for photo in obj:
        url=photo.get('url_c')
        photos = ET.dump(obj)
        print (photos)
```

However, either way has some problem:

1. some(many) images gathered do not match the "keyward" (eg. input "hand" may result in an image of mountain). Searching results are not "accurate".
2. it seems like the image download has an maximum limited([per_page](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) has max value 500). But I want to download images as many as possible.

Could anyone help me out how to fix my problems? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the first problem by adding:

```
sort="relevance"
```

in the arguments. Now the result images are much more relevant to the keywords.